# How can I access a table view delegate methods of one controller from another ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Here is the issue.

We have a pageview controller which creates view from another view controller that has a tableview in it. So after the view is created we would like to click on a cell of the tableview to run a function. Note that the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndex is not working.

I have put the delegate for the table view as the second one as I need to create header and footer for the table. I tried putting tableView:didSelectRowAtIndex in the view controller but it didn't work.

Then I thought of including a tapGesture for each of the cell but I need to show the details based on parameter from both the controllers. Hope you could help in this

Comment: didSelectRowAtIndex will "work."  Everybody has been using it for years now.  I'd suspect your own code first.  Note that you provide the method didSelectRowAtIndex, and it is called by the system, not by you, when someone taps.  Inside that method, you handle the tap.

Comment: can you post some code

Comment: I had accidentally disabled the selection in storybaord.

Answer (score 0):

Did you conform to table protocols of UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to set DataSource and Delegate method for table in perticular view.

```
tableView.dataSource = self;
tableView.delegate = self;
```

Write above code and check. You get all the delegate and datasource method for tableview.

Comment: I have set the dataSource and delegate to self in the view did load method of the second controller

Comment: You have to set delegate and datasource method for same controller at here your view is load. If you are in first view then we have to set delegete for first view only. You cannot set delegate for another view.

Answer (score 0):

I had accidently put the selection to no selection in stroyboard. The issue is fixed now.

Thanks for looking into this.